# How do I comment on a post and read messages in Instagram with requests, without using the facebook graph API?

Tags: node.js, instagram

I can log in and see posts, but I can't seem to comment on these posts pragmatically, and have 0 clue on how to read Direct Messages. Here is my code for logging in and getting media id.

```
// import axios from 'axios';
// import cheerio from 'cheerio';
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

class Instagram {

    async commentOnPost({ mediaURL, comment }) {
        console.log("here commentPost");

        let mediaId = await this.getMediaKey({ mediaURL });
        // post comment
        const url = `https://www.instagram.com/web/comments/${mediaId}/add/`;
        const data = {
            'comment_text': comment
        }

        let commentData;
        try {
            commentData = await this.session({
                method: "POST",
                url,
                form: data,
                headers: {
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                    'Referer': "https://www.instagram.com/" + mediaURL
                },
                json: true
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(commentData);
    }

async function testCase() {
    let i = new Instagram();
    await i.login({ username: "username", password: "password" });
    await i.getMediaKey({ mediaURL: "/p/B7PGlAKl5vx/" });
    await i.commentOnPost({ mediaURL: "/p/B7PGlAKl5vx/", comment: "pogchamp!" });
}
};
```

According to the logs, the code is submitting everything correctly, but I get a `403` error when I send a request to comment on a post. Anyone have experience with this? I have seen libraries like `https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api` but I am not sure how they work, nor how to replicate it in my code.

Comment: A 403 generally means you're not authorized to make that call. Are you sure your application is registered and permissions are granted to make a comment?

Comment: You're missing a ton of headers. The most obvious one which will cause this to fail is the missing x-csrftoken.

Comment: I have the csrf token as a global header, which was my mistake. I think the CSRF token changes every time

Comment: what does error 400 means ? i try to do same using jquery